# Resampling a raster with R

Tags: raster, r, resampling

I'm trying to use the R function resample between two non matching Raster objects. The raster to resample has the following description

```
hydrogate
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 1163, 1499, 1743337  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.00314077, 0.002236495  (x, y)
extent     : 8.49899, 13.207, 43.39997, 46.00102  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : GDAL.Band.Number.1 
values     : 0, 9  (min, max)
```

the one to which to resample is the following:

```
newhydromax
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 289, 372, 107508  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.01265, 0.009  (x, y)
extent     : 8.5, 13.2058, 43.4, 46.001  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 0, 0  (min, max)
```

I apply the resample function in the following way:

```
newhydrogatmax<-resample(hydrogate,newhydromax,method='ngb')
```

but the min-max values of newhydrogatmax are not 0,9 but 0,0:

```
newhydrogatmax
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 289, 372, 107508  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.01265, 0.009  (x, y)
extent     : 8.5, 13.2058, 43.4, 46.001  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : GDAL.Band.Number.1 
values     : 0, 0  (min, max)
```

I don't understand the reason of that

Answer (score 2):

You are resampling a high resolution raster to a lower resolution, using the "ngb" method. This returns the nearest neighbour of the high res raster to each of the low-res raster grid points.

If there's not many "9" values in the high res raster, there's a chance that all the low-res raster grid points are nearest to zeroes. So the low-res raster ends up as all zeroes.

I can reproduce this by creating a `hydrogate` with all zeroes except for one "9" at a location. I get all zeroes in the output.

If you resample with the default method, then it interpolates around the "9" and I get a max of 0.0016 in the output, because I guess the output grid point nearest the 9 is quite a distance, maybe three or four grid cell distances (this is approximately a 5x5 resampling).

The ngb method seems to ignore NA values when finding the nearest neighbour, so maybe what you want to do is set all zeroes to NA.